# Programmatically add Linear layout with five buttons placed horizontally with same size in both landscape and portrait

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout

i have programmatically creating linear layout with five buttons with fixed size, but when i change the orientation, the buttons are stretching in lanscape

here is my code:

```
LinearLayout button_layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    button_layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 100));
    button_layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    button_layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DCE1DC"));

FrameLayout layout = new FrameLayout(this);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(20, 80, 1));
    LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) layout.getLayoutParams();
    params.setMargins(30, 0, 30, 0);

    Button A = new Button(this);
    A.setLayoutParams(params);
    A.setText("A");
    button_layout.addView(A);
    Button B = new Button(this);
    B.setLayoutParams(params);
    B.setText("B");
    button_layout.addView(B);
    Button C = new Button(this);
    C.setLayoutParams(params);
    C.setText("C");
    button_layout.addView(C);
    Button D = new Button(this);
    D.setLayoutParams(params);
    D.setText("D");
    button_layout.addView(D);
    Button E = new Button(this);
    E.setLayoutParams(params);
    E.setText("E");
    button_layout.addView(E);
    linearLayout.addView(button_layout); //added button layout. 

    LinearLayout bottomBarLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    bottomBarLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 50));
    bottomBarLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    bottomBarLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8BC66D"));
    linearLayout.addView(bottomBarLayout); //added bottomBar layout .
```

below is my screen shots:

I want the buttons to be square in both the orientations with equal spaces, how to achieve this?

Comment: where is button_layout defined?

Comment: @EmilAdz sorry missed it , i have added now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this is what you are trying to achieve:

[image: Landscape]

Means, you want to have some space between the button and the wrapping layout such that you can set the background in it and the button itself isn't stretched. And, you need 5 buttons that have the same size in portrait and landscape view.

I took **your** code and made very few modifications: (*I use methods here just for more clean code*)

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_root);

    LinearLayout button_layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    button_layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 100));
    button_layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    button_layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DCE1DC"));

    button_layout.addView(createButton("A"));
    button_layout.addView(createButton("B"));
    button_layout.addView(createButton("C"));
    button_layout.addView(createButton("D"));
    button_layout.addView(createButton("E"));

    linearLayout.addView(button_layout);
}

/**
 * Create one button view
 * 
 * @param text
 * @return
 */
private LinearLayout createButton(String text)
{
    // wrapping button layout. The layout takes 20% from the parent layout
    LinearLayout oneButtonLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.2f);
    oneButtonLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
    params.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 0);
    oneButtonLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    // the button itself
    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(80, 80));
    button.setText(text);
    oneButtonLayout.addView(button);

    return oneButtonLayout;
}
```

The image above shows how it looks in the **landscape** view and this is how it looks in the **portrait** view:

[image: Portrait]

Hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the buttons get stretched is this:

```
button_layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 100));
```

You are setting the button layout width as `LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT`. So when you turn to horizontal orientation then this layout becomes bigger and the buttons have to adjust.

set here a fixed size and center this layout so the button appear always in the middle of the screen and you will get rid of the stretching problem.

Comment: No, thats is to set the size of the button layout, buttons and its sizes are related to frame layout

Comment: and also i want the buttonlayout to have fill parent so that the grey background will filll the screen in any case

Answer (score 0):

**1.Get display size** as show below..

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
```

Is deprecated, you should try this code instead:
first two line of code gives you the DisplayMetrics objecs. This objects contains the fields like heightPixels,widthPixels.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

metrics.heightPixels;
metrics.widthPixels;
```

**2.then set button size using those parameters**
something like this

```
A.setWidth(width/4);
A.setheight(height/4);
```

so on

```
B.setWidth(width/4);
B.setheight(height/4);
```

above ratio `1/4` was just for example use how much exactly u need or fits best for ur requirement